# Is China placing advertisements seeking to influence the upcoming American mid-term elections?

Tags: china, propaganda

As stated [here](https://www.scmp.com/news/world/united-states-canada/article/2165883/donald-trump-accuses-china-seeking-meddle-us) and in numerous other places,

> “We found that China has been attempting to interfere in our upcoming
>   2018 election, coming up in November, against my administration,”
>   Trump said in a speech to members of the UN Security Council.
>
> “China is actually placing propaganda ads in the Des Moines Register
>   and other papers, made to look like news,” he said.

Is anyone aware of such newspaper articles? Is there any substance to this claim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Des Moines Register [admits](https://www.desmoinesregister.com/story/money/agriculture/2018/09/24/china-daily-watch-advertisement-tries-sway-iowa-farm-support-trump-trade-war-tariffs/1412954002/) that it published a four-page advertisement of the (mainland) Chinese government.

The Des Moines Register, in the follow up article, says:

> "I think it's trying to maximize pressure on the administration to change its trade policies toward China by attempting to show White House and Republicans that they're going to pay a price with the mid-terms," said David Skidmore, a political science professor at Drake University.

...

> Kirk Leeds, CEO of the Iowa Soybean Association, said he's not surprised that China would target Iowa as well as other key election states.

...

> While the Register noted at the top of the page that the "China Watch" insert was a China Daily supplement, Skidmore said the newspaper should have made it clearer that the insert was paid advertising.

...

> For those readers who understood the supplement was an advertisement, Skidmore said, the approach "could backfire."
>
> Readers "may not appreciate trying to be manipulated by a foreign government," he said.

(The four page advertisement is also available through the above link)

Comment: Advertisement or not, does anyone consider any insert in a paper to be *the paper*?

Comment: @fredsbend This insert looks like 4 pages of the newspaper because of the format.